# how to divide a list into 3 lists based on id's in java

Tags: java, list

I have some data stored in a list. Now I have to divide this list into 3 lists based on the id.

Can anyone please help me do this in java?

I have a list like [{partyRoleId: 1, partyId:001, name:keer},{prtyRoleId: 1, partyId: 002, name:swathi},{partyRoleId: 1, partyId:003, name:ashok},{partyRoleId: 2, partyId:004, name:nag},{partyRoleId: 2, partyId:005, name:meg},{partyRoleId: 3, partyId:006, name:praveen},{partyRoleId: 3, partyId:007, name:jay}],

this is the list which i have , now can u notice that partyRoleId is different of some group of people , i have to list group of people who have partyRoleId as 1 is one list partyRoleId as 2 in another list and partyRoleId as 3 in other list ....
basically i need 3 list from one list

Comment: What is the first issue that's preventing you from moving ahead?

Comment: i have a list which consist of [id:1, name : keer,  id:1, name:bala,  id:1, name:sowmya, id:2 , name:nag,  id:2, name: ruine,   id: 3 , name: karthik]   , so now there are 3 different Id's , I have to list people of id 1 in one list and people of id 2 in other list and people of id 3 in other list , basically i want 3 list from the list of data using ids

Answer (score 1):

Unisng Java 8 streams, this can be done easily by something like

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result = list.stream()
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i % 3, Function.identity()));
```

where `i % 3` would have to be replaced by your logic to extract and group ids.

Answer (score 1):

Use a stream operation for this.

```
    List<Person> data = Arrays.asList(
            new Person(1, "001", "keer"),
            new Person(1, "002", "swath"),
            new Person(1, "003", "ashok"),
            new Person(2, "004", "nag"),
            new Person(2, "005", "meg"),
            new Person(3, "006", "praveen"),
            new Person(3, "007", "jay"));

    Map<Integer, List<Person>> threeLists
            = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getPartyRoleId));
```

Now we’ve got a map of three lists. We can take out each individual list like this:

```
    List<Person> personsWithPartyRoleId1 = threeLists.get(1);
    System.out.println("Persons with partyRoleId 1: " + personsWithPartyRoleId1);
```

> ```
> Persons with partyRoleId 1: [{ 1, 001, keer }, { 1, 002, swath }, { 1, 003, ashok }]
> ```

Similarly for the two other lists, of course. Or we can iterate all three lists in the map:

```
    threeLists.forEach((pri, list) -> System.out.println(
            "Persons with partyRoleId " + pri + ": " + list));
```

> ```
> Persons with partyRoleId 1: [{ 1, 001, keer }, { 1, 002, swath }, { 1, 003, ashok }]
> Persons with partyRoleId 2: [{ 2, 004, nag }, { 2, 005, meg }]
> Persons with partyRoleId 3: [{ 3, 006, praveen }, { 3, 007, jay }]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `id`s are integers, you can do it like so

```
for(Data d : fullList){
    switch(d.id % 3){
        case 0:
            list0.add(d);
            break;
         case 1:
            list1.add(d);
            break;
         case 2:
            list2.add(d);
            break; 
    }
}
```

If your `id`s are some other type, you can split it into 3 lists similarly with different criteria in the `switch`

Answer (score 0):

With help of lambda (Java 8 style) you can achieve this in one line. Let us say you have a list of Integers. You can create a map containing three lists using following

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> lists = ints.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i%3));
```

A more involving and complete example -

```
public class Simple {

    static class Person{
        // one can change this to private and create setter/getter
        public int id;
        public String Name;
        public Person(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", Name='" + Name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
                new Person(1, "Joe"),
                new Person(2, "Sam"),
                new Person(3, "Jan"),
                new Person(4, "Pat"),
                new Person(5, "Kal"),
                new Person(6, "Gro")
        );

       Map<Integer, List<Person>> lists = persons.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.id%3));
        System.out.println("How many lists: "+lists.size());
        lists.entrySet().forEach(es -> {
            System.out.println("Printing values of list: "+es.getKey());
            es.getValue().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.println("-------------------");
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so very much this worked for me as how i wanted:)

Comment: In that case you may want to select it as the right answer. It helps people with similar queries find this answer.